# リスト＜Bean＞型の要素をすべて取得したい

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

リスト＜Bean＞型の要素をすべて取得したいです。
今、`List<ItemBean> csvUpdate = csvInfo.findAll();`
のように、findAll()メソッドを使用したのですが、
メソッド findAll() は型 List で未定義です　とエラーが出ました。

findAll()がリストの要素をすべて取得するメソッドであると調べたら出てきたので、そう思っていました。どのように直せばよいのでしょうか？
ItemBeanクラスに

```
public class ItemBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String count;
    private String ispr;
    private String img;

    public ItemBean(){
        code ="";
        name ="";
        price ="";
        count ="";
        ispr ="";
        img ="";
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setIsPR(String ispr){
        this.ispr = ispr;
    }
    public String getIsPR() {
        return ispr;
    }

    public void setImage(String img){
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return img;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

/*     List＜ItemBean＞ list = new ArrayList();*/
}
```

のように書きました。ItemBeanクラスに

```
private String code;
    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String count;
    private String ispr;
    private String img;
```

の要素すべてが取得できるメソッドを書けばよいのでしょうか？
（その場合はどのように書けばよいのでしょうか？）
ちなみに、CSV出力のコントローラには

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //文字コードと出力するCSVファイル名を設定
           response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                   "attachment;filename=C:\\pleiades\\workspace\\hasuike\\jspServlet\\WebContent\\csv\\outputcsv");
           response.setContentType("MS932");
           ServletOutputStream so;
           List<ItemBean> csvInfo;
           csvInfo  = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();

            //try-with-resources文を使うことでclose処理を自動化
            try  {
                PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
                List<ItemBean> csvUpdate = csvInfo.findAll();
                for (int i = 0; i < csvInfo.size(); i++) {
                    String code = csvInfo.get(i).getCode();
                    String name = csvInfo.get(i).getName();
                    String unitPrice = csvInfo.get(i).getPrice();
                    String count = csvInfo.get(i).getCount();
                    String fav = csvInfo.get(i).getIsPR();

                    //CSVファイル内部に記載する形式で文字列を設定
                    String outputString =  code + "," + name + "," + unitPrice + "," + count + "," + fav
                             + "\r\n";

                    //CSVファイルに書き込み
                    pw.print(outputString);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


}
```

のように書きました。

Comment: csvUpdateが代入時以外使用されていないし、csvInfoも代入後に値が変更されているわけでもないので両者とも使用用途がよくわからないのですが、やりたいのはshallow copy(参照をコピー)でしょうかdeep copy(実体を複製)でしょうか？それによって回答がかなり変わってきます。(上のコードだけを見るとそもそもコピー自体が必要ないように見えます。)

Comment: 基本的に、コードを削ることは質問を明確にするためであれば歓迎されます。
しかし、削った結果が[「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコード」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)になるように注意する必要があります。
また、既に付いている回答と整合する形にすることも重要です。
ここ最近、質問者さんにより繰り返し行なわれている編集は上記の条件を満たしていないように思います。
また、編集時のコメントも常に「情報の修正」となっており、意図が解りません。
これが、何度でもロールバックされる原因です。
何かお困りでしたら、[メタサイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)の方でご相談いただくのがよいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> メソッド findAll() は型 List で未定義です　とエラーが出ました。

エラー内容の通りです。JavaのListクラスにはfindAllといったメソッドは実装されていません。

---

ここからは記載されているコードに対しての指摘です。

```
List<ItemBean> csvInfo;
csvInfo  = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
```

csvInfoに空のArrayListインスタンスを代入しています。

```
List<ItemBean> csvUpdate = csvInfo.findAll();
```

空のArrayListであるcsvInfoのfindAllメソッドを呼び出しています。
仮にfindAllというメソッドがあったとしても、
空のArrayListであるcsvInfoから何を取得したいのでしょうか？

コメントでも指摘されているようにこのコードからは何を行いたいのかがわかりません。

---

また質問タイトルにある「リスト＜Bean＞型の要素をすべて取得したい」であれば
以下の処理がそれに該当するものと思います。
csvInfoというListの要素をfor文によって全て取得しています。

```
for (int i = 0; i < csvInfo.size(); i++) {
    String code = csvInfo.get(i).getCode();
    String name = csvInfo.get(i).getName();
    String unitPrice = csvInfo.get(i).getPrice();
    String count = csvInfo.get(i).getCount();
    String fav = csvInfo.get(i).getIsPR();

    //CSVファイル内部に記載する形式で文字列を設定
    String outputString =  code + "," + name + "," + unitPrice + "," + count + "," + fav + "\r\n";

    //CSVファイルに書き込み
    pw.print(outputString);
}
```